How do you reduce the anger a mother feels towards her child?
I met a woman and things have been going well. Recently she has introduced me to her family (older sister and a niece). Her older sister is a widow.
Over the past couple of months, I've grown quite fond of the niece. We have emotionally bonded with each other. She clearly needs a father figure in her life and to be honest, I would not mind being that (it's all very healthy.) In all honesty, the two of us are fulfilling certain emotional needs in each other.
The girl is very nice with me, but with her mother it's different.
She keeps on defying her to get a rise out of her (it's working). Here it is winter, and this weekend the child asked her mother if she could go swimming. Her mother told her no, because going swimming in the winter is a bad idea, and she decided to jump in the pool anyway.
The mother started yelling at the child; she had a true meltdown. I have never seen a woman that angry before.
I look at the child and see just how much pleasure the response she is getting gives her. I pulled her out of the swimming pool and told her to go to her room. After a few moments, the mom calmed down.
You have already lost one parent and now you make your mother so angry that you risk losing another. If those school teachers of yours see one thing that leads them to suspect abuse in the house they are obligated by law to report it. You think the social worker will not take you away?
She starts crying and I tell her I don't want to hear it. I then tell her that I do intend to eventually marry into this family and I won't allow her to ruin it for me.
The thing is I'm a 35 year old bachelor that is having this parental role thrust on me. The mother should just have it go. If you give a child such control over your emotions, they will abuse it.
Luckily I was present to de-escelate the situation but I won't always be there to do so. How do I convince her to not spank angrily?

Hi and welcome. This is long, and some of it is repetitive (e.g. "sugar & spice" and "butter wouldn't melt" both) and/or irrelevant (what's a tamagotchi?) Paring it down and removing the unnecessary is likely to help you get quality feedback. Thanks.

I edited it for you; please take some time to choose your descriptions more wisely. This is a good site, and we're here to help, not to read unhelpful narrative (sorry.)

What exactly is your goal here? It looks like both mother and daughter escalate the situation, yet your explicitly stated questions only focus on the mother. Did the mother actually spank the daughter or has this only been threats?

As the impact of loosing a family member changes with time and age, what are the timescales involved? How long ago did the father die? How old is the daughter? Did mother and daughter actually get over the death already, or are they still in a phase of grieving?

Additionally, can you try to avoid using pronouns for this. When you use pronouns like 'she' and 'her' in a story about a sister, niece, a woman you met, and a mother those pronouns are very confusing for understanding the dynamics.

Hard to tell what's really happening here without knowing the age of the girl. Is she 3 or 16 ? This being said: most of what you describe sounds borderline abusive. That's a terrible and cruel way to talk to a child. I strongly advise you back off and re-assess your approach here.

I don't know if I've read this correctly but it seems like you're disciplining the daughter of the sister of the woman that you are dating? It would be one thing to start getting involved in the discipline of the woman you are dating (assuming you've discussed it with her) but to already be doing that with her niece is a little odd if I'm honest. I would hesitate to get involved with discipline of my own brothers daughter. I'd be interested to hear why you think it's your business to get involved (is your help even wanted?), and if you've discussed it with your new partner or the girls mother?

This post doesn't really appear to be about helping a mother reduce anger she feels towards a child, but is more around justifying your own opinions and actions. Closing as not a real question.

I am extremely worried about how you talked to this child here. Her parent has passed away and you are saying "You have already lost one parent and now you make your mother so angry that you risk losing another"? The child has already had a parent die. I don't think using the fear of a loss of another parent is an acceptable tactic with any child, let alone in this instance. This kind of language only has the practical upshot of fostering abandonment issues for her as well as ascribing guilt to her own parent's death. Similarly, telling her that 'someone is going to take her away' is very unlikely to help her change her behavior with the added bonus of decimating her level of stability and self-worth.
Later, you say you "don't want to hear it" when she starts crying and further ascribe a potential failure of your wish for a marriage to somehow be her fault.
Not only is she failing now, she might fail later. That's quite a bit of weight, shame, fear and undue guilt for a child.
All of this, because she went in the pool when she wasn't supposed to? Yelled at her mom?
I think it would be best if you took a big step back from trying to provide a parental role here, read some books, talked to some other people, and read some stuff on this site before continuing to shape this young lady's life.

Looking through the original version, you also threatened to 'beat her until she was black and blue'? This poor girl, oh my god.

Don't make things harder, stop being selfish, and stop being oblivious
I'm going to try to answer the question in the title of this and simply state that I don't think you've helped things, you've made them harder.
In the original draft of this, you said something that stood out to me as extremely concerning:

I'm a 35 year old bachelor that is having this parental role thrusted on me.

First and foremost, no you did not have that role thrust upon you. You chose to date this woman, she is a mother with a daughter, they are a package deal. You accept that or you leave. I'm not joking about this.
Throughout your post there's all this talk of things that you want to do and you burdening this woman's daughter by suggesting that she's going to screw things up for you. I genuinely don't know why the hell you would say something like that.
Stop being selfish
Additionally, you also said:

The mother should just have it be like water of a ducks back.

I'm a little shocked at how oblivious you are. You speak of wanting to marry this woman and it boggles my mind that you aren't aware of just how hard it is to be a parent. I would like to think that she's telling you about it all the time. Are you listening to her?
Stop being oblivious
Finally, you mentioned that your girlfriend's daughter really seems to enjoy spending time with you and listening to you. Your behavior and the things you've said have very likely forever altered your relationship with her daughter and not for the better. You might think that this outburst towards your girlfriend's daughter is going to make your girlfriend think you're supporting her, but there was probably half a dozen alternatives you could've used instead that didn't break the trust you've gained.
Stop making things harder

If it feels like I'm just trying to criticize all of your decisions here be aware, I am. As I read this, I see a very male-centric mindset that borders on toxic masculinity. Know that I am criticizing your ass man-to-man and I'm doing it because your mindset on parenting feels completely off-kilter to me. So here's some solutions to start making things easier:
Choose to be here
If you want to be involved with this woman, you need to choose to be a parent. Knock off this mindset you have where it's being thrust upon you. If you're going to date this woman, it's got to be an all-in from you because she very likely does not have time for someone that's only in it for themselves.
And be honest with yourself, if you don't think you want to choose to be a parent, please break things off and move on. I can tell you from experience that when I was in my 20s and single, I had a lot of requests on dating apps from attractive, single mothers probably because I had a lot of stability in my life. What I didn't get were a lot of requests from attractive people who were not mothers.
I knew that I did not want to be a father at that time and I chose to not engage. I don't know if you're thinking with your dick, but if so, knock it off. When it comes to step parenting, you have to choose to be involved. So you're either in or out, pick a side.
Listen actively
You can't be oblivious if you're choosing to be a parent. That luxury is gone now. You need to be listening to both your girlfriend and her daughter and you need to do so in a way that's as active as you can be.
To clarify what I mean, when your girlfriend is telling you about her day, shut up and just listen (and avoid that stuff where you're just waiting for your chance to talk). If you can, try to be doing nothing else when talking to her, turn your body to her and just listen. Maybe she wants to vent, maybe she's looking for ideas, but if you focus up and listen you're going to improve your understanding.
More active listening is going to help you understand how parenting permeates through every aspect of life. Almost every decision a parent makes is done so with consideration for their kids' welfare. What job do we take? What do we eat? What errands are we doing? What time are we doing those errands? How do we spend our money? Everything.
To exemplify, just last week I bought a new car. A significant factor for me was that it had climate controls in the rear because my kids are always telling me it's too hot in the back. Such a feature might be in the 'nice-to-have' column
for a 35-year old bachelor; it's in the 'must-have' column for a father.
When you're talking to your girlfriend's daughter, same thing. Listen actively. Young kids tell you all kinds of things and often they love it when they get to talk to an adult whose listening to them. You'll find that the things which are important to them aren't important to you, but it's important that you understand that they're important to them as it will help you to make better decisions. With regards to older kids, I don't have them so my knowledge is second-hand from my friends' teenager, but even then I strive to just listen to what she chooses to tell me and offer commentary only if it's requested.
Don't make decisions out of anger and use time outs if you need to
If you're going to be a parent then you need to be in control. If you're going to lash out in anger hoping to rule with fear, you will ultimately have a much harder time with a lot of things in part because your kids probably are going to be less likely to talk with you, thereby reducing what you can understand.
I don't know how old your girlfriend's daughter is. It sounds like maybe a young teenager, but regardless of age, short time outs are a useful tool when a parent feels like they're too mad. My wife and I describe them not as time outs for the kids, but rather time outs for ourselves. Or maybe 'Mom needs 20 minutes'.
The goal of this mindset is to remove the imminent danger element (i.e. swimming in winter), but reserving the final reaction for after you've had a chance to calm down.
Were I in your situation, I can understand taking the daughter out of the pool in a forceful way. It's not a situation where she's at risk of skinned knees, she's at risk of hypothermia and needing to go to a hospital. Given everyone's emotions are elevated, put her in her room with a towel and now the risks are much less which allow for a time out.
The daughter can change or just stay in her wet clothes, but if she picks the latter she's probably just going to be shivering and cold, she's not on the verge of putting herself in the hospital. This is fine, it's a natural consequence that's unpleasant. In the interim, you and the mom can discuss the behavior and figure out how to respond.
Support and Offer Alternatives
Your original question was how do keep your girlfriend from spanking her child in anger. The best way I can think of is to offer her alternatives that are better.
From reading everything, it sounds like your girlfriend regularly engages in corporal punishment which might border on some physical abuse. As an alternative, you've offered what I would honestly consider some psychological/emotional abuse. Neither of these are good in my opinion, as both are reliant on motivating through fear.
The most useful thing I can suggest at this stage, is to focus on your listening and improving your understanding of things so that you can offer more productive solutions that can help break a bad cycle.

Would it be helpful to take your girlfriend's daughter out with you on errands from time to time so that your girlfriend has some alone time? If you actively listen, you might know if that's a useful thing to offer.
Is your girlfriend's daughter mad at her mom for some reason, but refusing to tell her because she's afraid that she's going to be hit? If you can somehow recover your relationship with her daughter that she tells you this, then perhaps you can convey that to her mom on her behalf in a way that's easier to accept.

Do Chores
I'm not joking on this. Don't fall into the trap of thinking that the woman of the house does all the cooking, cleaning, laundry, etc.
It's Saturday and laundry is eternal. Move that along and be sure to fold what comes out of the dryer. The kitchen floor's gross? Don't complain about it, sweep and mop it. Everyone's got to eat, make something big enough to share and make sure it includes some vegetables.
Sometimes just removing the little irritations that is our floor feeling gross because the carpets need to be vacuumed can go a long way to making everyone's feeling less stressed.
Doing chores is going to help you understand that parenting is a lot of work. Actively taking on some of that work makes everything a little easier.

EDIT: A comment identified that I might have the relationships confused and this isn't your girlfriend's daughter, but rather her niece. Much of this advice still applies as you're still seeking to provide a father-figure role to this child effectively as an alloparent.
Alloparents can be important in the lives of children. A lot of people have a favorite teacher growing up, a lot also have a teacher they hated. If you want to be the former, try to listen more.
See, I needed to listen more. That's my bad.

They aren't dating the mother, but the mother's sister. (Not that it changes much of what you wrote, mind.)

@MisterMiyagi I think you're right, but I'm going to leave it as is since the advice is salient regardless since the querent indicated that they want to be a parent figure.

This answer is not going to be kind towards your role in all of this, because I think you significantly worsened the situation and are posting this with an undertone of being the sensible person, which I find genuinely worrying how tone-deaf it is.
My goal in this answer is not to berate, it is to inform; but several statements you make are inexplicably opposite to what I would consider a reasonable interpretation of the facts, and I'm sure my negative opinion on what you've done will inevitably shine through.
I also want to point out that I'm not blind to her mother's behavior, but it is limited to having a short temper, which is decidedly less damaging than all of your action's you've listed here. I suspect I don't have enough of a picture of the mother's overall attitude to formulate a response to the degree that I feel confident about your actions in all this.


Luckily I was present to de-escelate the situation

You:

told her "just how little force it takes to kill a person, and point out that her mother could kill you as a way of discussing the child's role in all or this
bring up her dead parent as a way to threaten them losing their other parent,
threaten physical abuse to the point of significant body bruising ("you will get a spanking from me and the color pallet of your ass cheecks will be much more varied than the rainbow if I do the spanking. Have I made myself clear?")
justified your role in all this by her "ruining it for you" for when you marry into this family, and said this to the child's face

and you think you de-escalated the situation?

This piece of bravado is off course completely fake and I sincerely hope the child never calls my bluff because I don't think I could ever spank a child.

I could focus on the troublesame nature of you calling this behavior of yours "bravado" (definition) but quite frankly there are bigger fish to fry here.
Do you believe that only physical violence is abuse? Because you're sweeping all the emotional/psychological abuse under the rug with that statement (among others) and your continued support of your own actions.

She clearly needs a father figure in her life and to be honest, I would not mind being that (it's all very healthy.)
I'm a 35 year old bachelor that is having this parental role thrust on me.

Who asked you to parent her? Because by your own words, you decided that she needed a father figure. You never mention anyone asking you to do so.
Just because you've not been met with resistance injecting yourself in this parental role does not mean that others implicitly "thrust this on you", as per your words.

She starts crying and I tell her I don't want to hear it.

Even if we put aside that you caused the crying (which I will get back to in my conclusion), you then indicate to her that you are not interested in her emotions.
What is your goal here? Getting her to no longer convey how she is feeling, instead shutting everyone out? Because that's what you explicitly made happen in this moment.

I then tell her that I do intend to eventually marry into this family and I won't allow her to ruin it for me.

After shutting her down emotionally, you then convey that you are judging her based on how she impacts your ability to marry into this family. You are directly confirming, to her face, that your opinion of her (and therefore your relationship with her) is based on how well she suits your goals, instead of who she is.
Even if we put aside everything else, in this paragraph alone your actions are causing her to emotionally detach from her environment. I cannot stress enough the long-lasting damage these kinds of things can do to any person by an acquaintance, let alone an impressionable teenager by a supposed parental figure in their life.

I usually try to give people the benefit of the doubt but you are nothing short of delusional about what is considered appropriate behavior around a child, let alone in the role of a parent.
A child getting a rise out of a parent is a relatively normal phenomenon. From experience, it is even more common with children who live with parents who are disproportionately quick to anger because (a) the parent embarrasses themselves, which is funny to them and (b) when the anger is so common, the child is desensitized to it and does not fear it.
Bringing up dead parents as a form of coercion in order to threaten the loss of the other parent, and threatening physical violence are emotionally and psychologically abusive behaviors. They are abhorrent and immoral in every conceivable sense, let alone this being an absolutely disproportionate response to what happened.
